# When movie or show script gets stolen long into filming

Tags: production

I remember reading something about Bryan Cranston's script getting stolen from his car at the time when he was playing Walter White of Breaking Bad. I can imagine something like this can totally throw a show off along with the audience eagerly waiting for every new episode.

So what would usually happen when actor's script containing key elements (i.e. finale spoilers) gets stolen mid-way through filming of a show/movie?

**Small clarification:** By "What happens" I mean things like i.e. *Does actor get penalized financially?* *Does the Script get re-written?* etc.

Comment: I suspect that "it depends". Loads of scripts (hundreds) were leaked when the Sony servers were hacked. None of them seem to have had any re-writes whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

Scripts go missing all the time. There are bunches of them in circulation at any time, color-coded. The color-coding isn't to find thieves, but to make sure everyone's working from the [same script](http://badassbard.blogspot.com/2011/07/color-coding-for-scripts-and-film.html).

A friend of mine, back in the '70s, paid his way through college by taking old scripts and selling them, which couldn't possibly have been legal—but nobody cared. (Same friend is now the head of a major production company.) I mention this because this whole "nobody can see the script!" is a relatively new, and probably still a pretty rare thing. (I mean, do you suppose that the producers of, at random, "Fuller House", care if someone gets a copy of the script?) With certain high-profile exceptions, like the comic book/sci-fi stuff, "script security" isn't a big issue.

As Daniel points out, above, nothing from the Sony hack seems to have had any influence on what got put on screen, with the possible exception of *The Interview* being scuttled.

I've never *heard* of anyone being charged for losing a script, but I can't swear it hasn't happened. I saw the printing end of it a lot, and it seemed like there were always plenty of extras as a rule.